# If have Magento 3 why not we migrate mangento platform to microservice?

Tags: architecture

I've researched about Monolithic vs Microservice architecture. And I recognized microservice if it apply for magento it will resolve all exist problems of magento has.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Microservice architecture can certainly bring benefits to Magento, but it's not a silver bullet that will solve all existing problems.

And There is currently no Magento 3 available. As of March 2023, the latest version of Magento is 2.4.4.